# How do I install pygame with cmd?

Tags: python, pip, pygame, pycharm

I have an idea for a game that uses the module `pygame`. The thing is, I don’t know how to install it.

I have tried to open up cmd and type:

```
pip install pygame
```

But it came up with an error saying:

```
pip is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

Please help me.

Comment: *"pip is not recognized as an internal or external command"* - So this problem has nothing to do with Pygame as you cannot use "pip".

Comment: Firstable you need to install pip properly.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-can-i-install-pip-on-windows Then try again

Answer (score 0):

To install pygame you need to write the command:

`pip install pygame`

in your command prompt, if that does not work try:

`pip3 install pygame`

If that fails, make sure to install python from [this link](https://www.python.org/downloads/).
Make sure to add python and pip to your environment path. Restart your computer and then try again!

If you have already installed python, try running the installer again and this time including pip in the environment path or you can add it manually, [this link](https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/) will help you do this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the path of your pip installation to your PATH system variable.
After this, use: `pip install pygame`

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like you don't have pip installed on your system. You should download it first.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).